# jquery fullCalendar not mapping time in chrome and IE browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fullcalendar

facing issue with fullcalendar in time mapping in chrome and IE. But working fine in firefox. I am adding snapshot here
FIREFOX: firefox view

[image]

But in case of chrome, the look is different
chrome view

[image]

But when I open the the more tools-> Developer Tool for debug in chrome, it automatically adjust to the correct time.

When stop debug mode, it keep the same position.

Here is sample code.

```
$('#scheduleView').fullCalendar({
        height: "auto",
        buttonHtml: {
            prev: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
            next: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        allDayText: "",
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        events: finalJsEventList,
        scrollTime: "00:10:00",
        slotDuration: "00:20:00",
        editable: true,
        droppable: false, 
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {},
eventMouseover: function (calEvent, jsEvent){}
});
```

Here's a sample of the event data:

```
EVENTLIST= 
  { title:"Strawberry Laser Treatment (4)", start:"2017/06/26 11:00:00", end:"2017/06/26 11:50:00" }, 
  { title:"Strawberry Laser Treatment (4)", start:"2017/06/28 09:30:00", end:"2017/06/28 10:20:00" }, 
  { title:"Strawberry Laser Treatment (4)", start:"2017/06/30 09:30:00", end:"2017/06/30 10:20:00" }
```

Comment: can you supply the event JSON please? Then we can reproduce the example.

Comment: EVENTLIST={
{ 
title:"Strawberry Laser Treatment (4)",
start:"2017/06/26 11:00:00",
end:"2017/06/26 11:50:00"
}, 
{
title:"Strawberry Laser Treatment (4)",
start:"2017/06/28 09:30:00",
end:"2017/06/28 10:20:00"
},
{
title:"Strawberry Laser Treatment (4)",
start:"2017/06/30 09:30:00",
end:"2017/06/30 10:20:00"
}

Comment: seems fine to me in Chrome (v58.0.3029.110): http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/4/ The events are where they should be from the beginning.

Comment: Did you try format your date differently?  For example: 2017-06-30T11:00:00 is standard when you .format()  a moment object